# can @media queries be inline?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am currently writing a responsive html signature for work and I am having issues with google stripping my CSS making my mobile table visible in the browser. Is it possible to add the @media query inside the table so it doesn't get stripped by Google?

Comment: Are you saying that your media queries are being stripped?  Which browser(s) is doing this?

Comment: Probably external/internal css not work on email  signature . You may use table using % and all css inline. ex.<body style="background:#999">

Comment: Yes google mail completely strips out my CSS settings on fonts, size and table cell sizes. Its only happening in google mail.